# How to debug Service Fabric stateful service / actor state

Tags: actor, azure-service-fabric

I implemented a basic Service Fabric `StatefulService` that stores questionnaire data using its `IReliableStateManager`. In order to debug a method, I would need to view the `StateManager` data using some sort of browser or administration console. It doesn't seem to be possible using the Service Fabric Explorer.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to expose APIs that allow reading of the data and create the viewer as part of your application. There is no generic way to do this today.

Comment: Thanks. That's quite limiting. So I suppose it would be best to use the StateManager as a persistent cache rather than a primary data store?

Comment: @Spiff you can user Actors and Reliable Collections as primary data store, but it will cause troubles if actor model or key-value storage does not model your business objects. For example, storing lists in a reliable collection is possible, but not a good idea.

Comment: @cassandrad Could you elaborate on that or can you point me to resources that deal with this aspect?

Comment: @Spiff there are a lot of questions on the subject on SO, just search for “[azure-service-fabric] list”. The main problem with lists stored in RC is that as they get larger, the time spent on serialization and transferring data to secondary replicas increases as well. And every time when you want to just get count of elements in such list, you need to retrieve it completely, which can take sensible amount of time in some conditions.